# Adventurer 3 Not loading Filament/Grinding Sound

Tags: flashforge-adventurer-3, flashforge

Have had my second Adventurer 3 now about 3 weeks.  Used all of the red filament that comes with it but when I go to load new FlashForge filament in the unit, I can't even get it to suck up the filament.  I just get a grinding sound like something is majorly wrong.  Any ideas please?  The filament will not even make it to the extruder.

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure there is a clean cut on the end. No fraying or angle. A straight clean cut. Then when loading push it a little. Give the filament a little help. It's worked for me.